# Issue with Database Scoped Credential in SSDT (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

Having an issue importing a Database Scoped Credential into SSDT.

Using SSMS on an Azure SQL Database I created a Database Scoped Credential which I used to create an External Data Source to connect to External Tables. All that works fine in SSMS and I can see everything I created in sys.database_scoped_credentials, sys.external_data_sources, sys.external_tables, and I can access the external tables fine.

I imported the database into a Database Project in Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT version 15.1). The Database Scoped Credential didn't import, so the External Data Source can't  find it and the build fails.

Error Code: SQL71501: SQLExternalDataSource: [myExternalDataSource] has an unresolved reference to SqlDatabaseCredential [myCredential].

Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I resolved this error by right-clicking on "Security > Add > New Item... > Credential"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any object that doesn't get created automatically during the import operation can be manually created. For a DB-scoped credential, it'd be something like:

- Right-click on the database project in Solution Explorer and then click on Add New Item
- Search for and select Script (Build) and name it after your DB-scoped credential
- In the SQL Server Object Explorer window, right-click on the DB-scoped credential and select View Code
- Copy and paste the DB-scoped credential's definition from the View Code tab into the DB-project tab.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I manually imported the Database Scoped Credential script and now the model gets validated. Now in the next step, the auto-generated deployment script fails on the CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [mySource] statement which uses that credential.

SQL72014 .Net SqlClient Data Provider... Incorrect syntax near 'EXTERNAL.

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Could you be more specific with regard to fails?  As in, does the database project fail to build? Does that error come when you're attempting to publish the database project to an instance of SQL Server (e.g. SQL Server 2014)?  There are a handful of different scenarios in which that error could be seen...

Comment: I haven't yet got to the point of deploying to an Azure SQL Database (although that's the end goal). Right now I've just download the database schema from an Azure SQL database into Visual Studio and tried to make it build. The last lines of the output are:

An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
Done building project "MyDatabaseProject.sqlproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I suspect this may have been a known issue that was fixed in the most recent version of SSDT.  Have you downloaded and installed the most recent version of SSDT? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt)

Comment: Yup I have the most recent version. I think I realized my problem - the build was OK but the error was in the deployment step. I will mark as solved, thanks for the help.